# Qiskit - lesson 3 - with Abe

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices

Coding for Qiskit

I watched this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrUTwq5jKM4

Using Mac OS Big Sur
Using Jupyter 2.0.8
Using Python 3.8

The below code did not work and therefore installed pylatexenc ('pip install pylatexenc') It installed successfully. I then restarted jupyter and It still prints the same error. When I try to reinstall pylatexenc  - it says it already there. I tried running while Jupyter is on and in a new terminal (Mac) window I tried to reinstall it- get the same message. Tried 'import pylatexenc *' at beginning of code - does not work - any advice

Code:

```
from qiskit import *
from pylatexenc import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)

cr = ClassicalRegister(2)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)

%matplotlib inline

circuit.draw()

circuit.h(qr[0])

circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

Here is the error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bd220039ee1c> in <module>
----> 1 circuit.draw(output='mpl')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py in draw(self, output, scale, filename, style, interactive, plot_barriers, reverse_bits, justify, vertical_compression, idle_wires, with_layout, fold, ax, initial_state, cregbundle)
   1496         from qiskit.visualization import circuit_drawer
   1497 
-> 1498         return circuit_drawer(self, scale=scale,
   1499                               filename=filename, style=style,
   1500                               output=output,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/visualization/circuit_visualization.py in circuit_drawer(circuit, scale, filename, style, output, interactive, plot_barriers, reverse_bits, justify, vertical_compression, idle_wires, with_layout, fold, ax, initial_state, cregbundle)
    221                                       cregbundle=cregbundle)
    222     elif output == 'mpl':
--> 223         image = _matplotlib_circuit_drawer(circuit, scale=scale,
    224                                            filename=filename, style=style,
    225                                            plot_barriers=plot_barriers,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/visualization/circuit_visualization.py in _matplotlib_circuit_drawer(circuit, scale, filename, style, plot_barriers, reverse_bits, justify, idle_wires, with_layout, fold, ax, initial_state, cregbundle)
    515 
    516     global_phase = circuit.global_phase if hasattr(circuit, 'global_phase') else None
--> 517     qcd = _matplotlib.MatplotlibDrawer(qubits, clbits, ops, scale=scale, style=style,
    518                                        plot_barriers=plot_barriers, layout=layout,
    519                                        fold=fold, ax=ax, initial_state=initial_state,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/visualization/matplotlib.py in __init__(self, qubits, clbits, ops, scale, style, plot_barriers, layout, fold, ax, initial_state, cregbundle, global_phase, qregs, cregs)
    126         self.plt_mod = plt
    127         if not HAS_PYLATEX:
--> 128             raise ImportError('The class MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc. '
    129                               'to install, run "pip install pylatexenc".')
    130         self._clbit = []
```

Comment: Hi, just a few questions : what is the qiskit version you use? You can check via `import qiskit.tools.jupyter` and then run `%qiskit_version_table`. Also, does the drawing work when you just do this `circuit.draw()` ? Could you restart your notebook and run it without this line `from pylatexenc import *` and tell me what it did? And last, do you have matplotlib installed? You can check if it is by running this line on your notebook `!pip list`.

Comment: {'qiskit-terra': '0.17.4', 'qiskit-aer': '0.8.2', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.13.1', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.1', 'qiskit': '0.26.2', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to make sure you are installing your packages in the environment where you are running is installing them from the Jupyter notebook. You can do that with `!pip` command in one of the cells:

```
!pip install pylatexenc
```